# Damselfly identification

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Can somebody identify this damselfly? Found near a stream about 15 miles west of Boston.[image]

Comment: I would have called that a Blue Darner, but apparently that's been a local Missouri name and not a real name this whole time, so I don't know what the real name would be. It was even called Blue Darner on the official FFA entomology exams.

Comment: It be an [Argia anceps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Argia_anceps.jpg), but the shade of blue is a little off. The pattern of black marks looks close though. Wikipedia points out that many damselfly species have very similar appearances.

Comment: @user137 is it September 19th already?

Comment: @arboviral What does September 19 have to do with it?

Comment: @user137 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Talk_Like_a_Pirate_Day ("It be [...]"). :)

Comment: @arboviral You mean you don't talk like that every day?

Comment: Just got word from a biologist from State of Mass......“Violet Dancer” (Argia fumipennis)

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me like a male [Argia fumipennis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_dancer) violacea

Comment: Some additional details, reason(s) for why you think it's a male, and an embedded image would be good to see in your answer. +1 if you can do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The [damselfly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damselfly) in question belongs to the subspecies ***Argia fumipennis violacea***. The species as a whole are referred to as [variable dancers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_dancer), however, this subspecies most commonly goes by "violet dancer".

As mentioned in another answer, this is in fact a male, which is most easily observed by the overall purple body color, as well as the blue accenting on the end segments of the abdomen. In contrast, a female will have a brown body color; both male & female have wild black markings throughout the abdomen, and transparent wings. Consider the following for comparison.

[image]
*Female on left; male on right.*

And then, a general image to match the one you provided:

[image]

> Found near a stream about 15 miles west of Boston.

Differing from most other genera within the family [Coenagrionidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coenagrionidae), dancers are generally found along *moving* water, so this sounds spot on. They seem to live quite comfortably *around* your area, however, according to this illustration, they aren't well documented within MA itself.

[image]
[(Source)](http://explorer.natureserve.org/servlet/NatureServe?searchName=Argia%20fumipennis)